# Suggesting avoidance of multiple questions

Tags: support, allowed-questions

Where should I point users to avoid multiple unrelated questions in a single post?

I know from experience that a single posted question should contain either one question or only very closely related questions, but what actual guideline does this fall under?

The [How to Ask](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page mentions avoiding vague questions, but I can't find anything which actually asks users to avoid multiple questions per post.

Comment: How about http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44301/13992 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2995/13992 or http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120633/13992 or...

Comment: Ah, I wrongly assumed that searching in meta would include results from *all* metas.

Comment: So I can't vote to close by linking to the [FAQ suggestion that a question should be a single question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122361/faq-suggestion-that-a-question-should-be-a-single-question-self-contained?lq=1) because it's on a different meta. How should I handle this question?

Comment: Instead of asking what does MSO say about multiple questions, just ask what to do with multiple questions