# Questions which ask multiple unrelated questions

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/125742/when-you-break-a-glass-block-can-you-get-it-back-can-you-break-a-glass-pane-and) just came in, and it's a single question with several different unconnected questions contained within. Should I answer ALL the questions, or does the question need splitting up to make more sense?

This is per [this meta question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5754/suggesting-avoidance-of-multiple-questions).

Answer (score 5):

As long as the questions are related ("Do I get the glass block back?" + "Do I get the glass plane back?"), they can usually remain in one question. The idea is roughly the same, even though the answers may or may not be the same.

If they are largely unrelated, however ("How to repopulate my village?"), they should be separated, as Robotnik has done now.

Overall: Use best judgement.

Comment: From what I can tell, Robotnik just got rid of half the question, and the user never made it into a separate question.

Comment: The wording in my post may have been a little off, but yes, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: @shanodin - To my credit, I did tell him why I removed it, pointed him to a question that might help, and said if that if it didn't, he was welcome to ask that part as a separate question. It's possible the answers on that other question solved his problem :)

Comment: @Robotnik I'm not condemning what you did at all, I just wasn't sure what the right thing to do was since he asked two questions but seemed to only get one answer. Sorry if it came across like I was criticising - just trying to understand :)

Comment: @shanodin - oh, no that's fine, I didn't think you were criticising :). Its just a general rule of mine, if I edit a new user's post I usually try to explain why to them (and help point them at a possible solution if I can).